# Spring Tomcat 403 forbidden

Tags: java, spring, tomcat7

I can't understand while send ajax request from phonegap spring return 403 error without handle request with tomcat. If use jetty embeded work cool.

my controller

```
@Controller
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String test() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

How i can full log requests in tomcat or how fix it from spring. In simple rest clients work cool.

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Object loginUser1(HttpServletRequest req , HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {
    Enumeration<String> headerNames = req.getHeaderNames();

    while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {

        String headerName = headerNames.nextElement();
        System.out.println(headerName);

        Enumeration<String> headers = req.getHeaders(headerName);
        while (headers.hasMoreElements()) {
            String headerValue = headers.nextElement();
            System.out.println(headerValue);
        }

    }
    return "Hello";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Object loginUser2(HttpServletRequest req , HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {
    Enumeration<String> headerNames = req.getHeaderNames();

    while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {

        String headerName = headerNames.nextElement();
        System.out.println(headerName);

        Enumeration<String> headers = req.getHeaders(headerName);
        while (headers.hasMoreElements()) {
            String headerValue = headers.nextElement();
            System.out.println(headerValue);
        }

    }
    return "Hello";
}
```

Get return

> host
>   10.0.0.42:8080 connection keep-alive accept
>   */*
>   x-requested-with com.citronium.planReview user-agent Mozilla/5.0
>   (Linux; U; Android 4.2.1; en-us; e2001v21_v89_gq2008s Build/JOP40D)
>   AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile
>   Safari/534.30 accept-encoding gzip,deflate accept-language en-US
>   accept-charset utf-8, utf-16, *;q=0.7

Comment: check catalina.out log file for hints of what has happened. If you see any stacktraces there, post them here

Comment: Are you GET'ing or POST'ing? Your controller only allows POST'ing - that might be your problem.

Comment: Get work cool! Catalina show only 403 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve my problem. In Servlet 3, is the direction `WebSockets`. Tomcat 7 try implement Servlets 3 and start websocket listener. Phonegap< not send header *Origin*, tomcat not resolve any strange origins as: "null, file://" and other. Use other servers or, use old tomcat. I am use tomcat 6.37. It's resolve my problem.

Answer (score -2):

Probably you need as @Anders said:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

If you want to add logging to your web application, you can add [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html), which is a good logging framework.

At applicationContext-security.xml define

`<intercept-url pattern="/default-page" access="permit all">`

Comment: You also need to define to your web.xml the default page.

Comment: this REST based controller. not have view.

Comment: When you return "Hello", in the above example, you have mapped the "/" to a Hello.jsp page... It does not return a string, it returns  a view.

Comment: I am found servers send 403 while request is "OPTIONS"

Comment: Try method=RequestMethod.OPTIONS to RequestMapping